# How can I disconnect from instead of kill the external process when debugging with "attach" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In VS Code, when using an "attach" debug configuration to attach the debugger to an existing process, although the debug toolbar defaults to showing the "detach" option for stopping debugging, the "stop" option is still available in the menu - and will kill the process (losing any unsaved work).

Is there a way to specify in launch.json (or anywhere else) for this configuration that it should *never* terminate the process, even when "stop" is pressed? This would be helpful, to avoid losing any work by accidentally doing "stop" instead of "detach".

It also feels like since VS Code didn't actually start this process, and doesn't really know anything about it, it might be sensible for there to be a way to tell VS Code not to kill it.

My launch.json is fairly bare, but I couldn't find any options that would seem to help.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Whatever",
      "processId": "15496",
      "sourceFileMap": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading through the discussion in [Debugger: Add option to allow disconnect and stop/terminate UI elements #116731](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116731) (which I found by googling "`github vscode issues debugger attach stop detach`"), you have a couple of options:

1. Use the `Debug: Disconnect` command in the command palette
2. Use the context menu of the call stack view where there should be a similar option.
3. Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> while hovering the mouse over the stop button, which- if I understand correctly- changes it to disconnect rather than stop (the icon of the button should change accordingly as well).

I don't know of a way to make the stop button change to be a "disconnect" button by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - yes, I've seen that discussion. I'm aware of the 'detach' option, and detaching the debugger isn't a problem, it's simply that I want to configure the 'stop' option to be unavailable (or for it to do the same as 'detach') so that there is no possibility of VS Code killing the process, even if clicking stop by accident.