# How to execute a specific command when stopping the debug mode in VS Code?

Tags: vscode-debugger

I am debugging a program using GDB in the `launch` requesr manner of VS Code.

[Image: The stop button of debug icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n86Cq.png)

Now I found that VS Code will simply `kill -s SIGKILL` the program **WHEN** I stopping the debug mode.

But I want execute a customed command when stopped, maybe I can achive it by adding some specific setting items in the `launch.json` file?

> NOTE: I have noticed the `postDebugTask` settings in the launch.json, but the directive will run the extra task **AFTER** VS Code killed the program which is debugging instead of **WHEN**, actually I want to change the VS Code's default action **WHEN** stopping the program.

The following is the content of my `launch.json` file, can anyone help me?

```json
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch Nginx",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
            "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
            "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: related but not applicable here because you're using a launch request: [How can I disconnect from instead of kill the external process when debugging with "attach" in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76556814/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

For set custom command when debugger is stopped, you have to follow specific steps

**Step 1 :** create tasks.json file as per show in screenshot

**Step 2 :** Add `postDebugTask` attribute in launch.json and set tasks.json's label here

Now when you stop debugger , command will run automatically

[image: Script File]

[image: launch.json File]

[image: Task.json File]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have alse noticed the `postDebugTask` settings in `launch.json`, but the directive will run the extra task **AFTER** VS Code killed the program which is debugging instead of **WHEN**, actually I want to change the VS Code's default action **WHEN** stopping the program.

Comment: means , you want to replace  stop debug command with your custom command ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, but it looks like a bit tricky. @I_am_prince

Comment: user can't change default function of vsCode. another way is, you can create your own custom extension for vs code and add one button in that toolbar , and do what you want onClick of that button.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, I will search for some tutorials about creating a custom VS Code extention. @I_am_prince